# DotNetOpenAuth with log4net 1.2.11

Tags: log4net, dotnetopenauth

Is there a way to make `DotNetOpenAuth` logging  work with the new version of `log4net`?

For some reason it doesn't seem to work for me (I tried both the old and the new `publicKeyToken` of `log4net`).

Thanks

Comment: Can you please specify what version exactly of log4net you're trying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried a binding redirect?

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="**key**" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="**versionDNOAbuiltWith**" newVersion="**yourversion**" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: Why would this be needed though?  Is it because DotNetOpenAuth is 3.5?

Comment: It's because log4net makes breaking changes in "patch" release versions, and includes the patch version number (major.minor.patch) in the `[AssemblyVersion]` attribute, forcing everyone to recompile every time a new version is issued and agree on the version -- or use a binding redirect.